# Using jQuery Mobile In Native/Offline App

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use jQuery Mobile in a native app where the HTML/JS/CSS files are bundled with the app and stored locally? The examples I see all use AJAX responses for displaying the different views.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how could you not bump into this before, but there you have it:

http://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap

And it plays nicely with ajax.